# Using Map function inside the render() -> return() but it's not getting displayed

Tags: reactjs

I am learning React and having trouble in rendering list (ul>li's) using map function inside a **UL** `JSX` element inside a render function. I searched on internet but unable to resolve the issue. 
Below is my component code:(in this component implementing the Pagination)

**Code snippet:**

```
    //function returning list with values 1-total_pages e.g total_pages=5
        make_pages_list = (start, end, step) => {
        return Array.from(Array.from(Array(Math.ceil((end-start+1)/step)).keys()), x => start+ x*step);
    }

render() {
   return(
      <div>
      <div>Hi there
       <form>
           <input type="text"/>
           <input type="submit"/>
       </form>
      </div>
     ........ 
     //other JSX elements are also there
    //then
                    <div>
                        <div className='ui container'>
                            <ul style={{listStyle: "none"}}>
                                {this.make_pages_list(1,this.state.total_pages, 1).map((n) =>{
                                   <li key={n} id={n}><a href="#">{n}</a></li>    
                                }
                                )}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

   )

}
```

Additionally:
I have also the module `"react-addons-create-fragment"` but then style of ul is not working on it.

Comment: Your `.map()` function is not returning anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should `return` from map function

```
{this.make_pages_list(1,this.state.total_pages, 1).map((n) =>{
   return <li key={n} id={n}><a href="#">{n   }</a></li>    
}
)}
```

or

```
{this.make_pages_list(1,this.state.total_pages, 1).map((n) =>(
   <li key={n} id={n}><a href="#">{n   }</a></li>    
)
)}
```

Comment: When you add the `return` what happened?